# How do you fill in a resource string at run-time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localization, resources, resx

I have an application I'd like to localise. However, the strings to be localised occasionally contain parts I'd like to provide at runtime, such as action links.

For example, I have a string like this: `Please <a href="/help">click here</a> for help.` I can't just split it into two resources since in different languages it'll be in a different location.

Is there any way to do this or should I stick to hard-coding the link to the controller/action in the resource itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify your string this way:

```
 string.Format("Please {0]click here{1} for help", "<a href="/help">","</a>")
```

Now, the first string   `"Please {0]click here{1} for help"` can be easily translated/localized, even if the order of your text changes:

```
"Für Hilfe klicken Sie bitte {0}hier{1}."
```

Answer (score 1):

The approach I ended up taking was creating a resource string like this:

```
"Please {0} for help."
```

Which would then be filled at run-time using a String.Format and a resource for `"Click Here"` which I already had defined.